# I am trying to install angular 8 but it giving me error I tried so much but its not working?

Tags: node.js, angular8

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCUE.png)
I am sharing screenshot of error where I am stuck

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

You should see if npm package is Globally installed. If don't check your_projet_folder_/node_modules/bin/ng and then execute it.